# Is -print a useless option for find now?

Tags: bash, find

I just tried :

```
find . -name "*.[hc]" -print
```

and

```
find . -name "*.[hc]"
```

But both output the same ,is `-print` useless now?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the man page under FreeBSD, I see:

```
 -print  This primary always evaluates to true.  It prints the pathname of
         the current file to standard output.  If none of -exec, -ls,
         -print0, or -ok is specified, the given expression shall be
         effectively replaced by ( given expression ) -print.
```

So in many cases, `-print` is unnecessary.  However, consider this expression that looks for a file named `foo` inside of `somedir`, but not inside any directory named `.snapshot`:

```
find somedir -name .snapshot -prune -o -name foo
```

Given the description referenced above, this will be transformed into:

```
find somedir ( -name .snapshot -prune -o -name foo ) -print
```

Which is not the same as what was probably intended:

```
find somedir -name .snapshot -prune -o -name foo -print
```

Adding parentheses to make the group a bit more obvious, this is:

```
find somedir ( -name .snapshot -prune ) -o ( -name foo -print )
```

To spot the difference, notice that both `-prune` and `-print` evaluate to `true`.  So without specifying `-print`, the first version will print out the current file if *either* `-name .snapshot` or `-name foo` matches.

The second version will only output the current file if `-name foo` matches.

This is a long winded way of saying that `-print` is not generally necessary as long as you understand the situations in which it is necessary.

Comment: Incidentally, this was fun.  I hadn't realized the subtleties of this before.  Thanks, locale!

Comment: @larsks,what does it mean by `This primary always evaluates to true`?

Comment: @locale: Exactly what it says. `find` is a huge logical expression evaluator, and some of its predicates have side effects as well as returning a boolean value.

Comment: You give `find` a bunch of boolean expressions -- like `-name foo`, which evaluates to True when a file is named `foo`.  Expressions like `-print` or `-prune` don't really specify a condition, so they always evaluate to True.

Comment: @larsks,why don't just use `-print` since they always evalutes to `true`,isn't it duplicate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: @locale, I think it means that the options can have two outcomes. Firstly they evaluate to true/false as part of deciding if a file "matches". Secondly they have side effects, like printing the name of the file. `-print` is only used for this side-effect so the boolean value is set to true. If it were set to false, later options (whose side effects you want) might not get evaluated. Consider `find . -name foo -mtime 3 -print -exec touch {} \;` if -print were false, a typical short-circuit evaluation algorithm would not evaluate the -exec. There is an implicit "and" between the options.

Answer (score 0):

It's also useful when you do other things, but still want to see the matches.

This is a common script call for me:

```
find . -name '*somepattern*' -print -delete
```